# client_token is not defined

Tags: python, python-requests

here is my code:

```
import requests
import sys

# Vars && Args
user = sys.argv[1]
password = sys.argv[2]
vault_kv_path = sys.argv[3]
application_path = sys.argv[4]
vaultUrl = "https://vault-url/"


def genToken(vaultUrl):
    url = vaultUrl + '/v1/auth/ldap/login/' + user
    headers = {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
    payload = {"password":""+password+""}
    resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
    data = resp.json()
    auth = data['auth']
    client_token = auth['client_token']
    return client_token


def listAppSecrets(vaultUrl, client_token):
    url = vaultUrl + '/v1/' + vault_kv_path
    headers = {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Vault-Token': '{}'.format(client_token)
    }
    resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    data = resp.json()
    return data

vault = genToken, listAppSecrets(vaultUrl, client_token)
```

when i try, requests.get in `listAppSecrets(vaultUrl, client_token)` function, i got error in client_token, how can i fix this?

Note client_token is returned to another function passing the value.

```
NameError: name 'client_token' is not defined
```

Comment: You need to call `genToken` first: `vault = listAppSecrets(vaultUrl, genToken(vaultUrl))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `client_token` before passing it to `listAppSecrets`:

```
client_token = getToken(vaultUrl)
vault = listAppSecrets(vaultUrl, client_token)
```